# external $.ajax function with parameters like url, method data and data returned to pass

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to create a web site that will be heavily using ajax(jquery).  for this I would like to use an external $.ajax function and pass the parameters as and when needed. I would like a full example to guide me.  I am using php on the server side and data returned will be json.  I have no problem on the server side, but cant get the any of the ajax working.  please any help in terms of examples will be very much appreciated.

my first example I did was as the following

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset = "utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>


$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#find").click(function(){

            $.ajax({
                // the URL for the request
                url: "findPatient.php",
                // the data to send (will be converted to a query string)
                data: {pnhsno: $('#search').val()},
                // whether this is a POST or GET request
                type: "GET",
                // the type of data we expect back
                dataType : "json",


                // code to run if the request succeeds;
                // the response is passed to the function
                success: function(json){

                    $("#ex1").val(json[0].firstname);

                }


            });


        });
});

</script>


<link rel = "stylesheet" type ="text/css" href = "pascss/patient.css " >
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">  

<form class="form-patient" ">
<fieldset>
<legend>Patient Details</legend>
<label for="ex1">First name</label>
<input type="text" name="ex1" id="ex1" />
</fieldset>
</form>

<form class="form-wrapper">
<fieldset>
<legend>Find Patient</legend>
    <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Enter patient NHS number" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Find" id="find" onclick =">


    </fieldset>
</form>



</div>

</body>
</html>
```

even this example is not fully working.  it seems to be it is getting the right json back 
and displays it on the text box for a milisecond just before it finishes completing the document.ready funtion. when it finish wipes the text appended on the text box again.  I just cant understand it.  can please someone explain it for me.  many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Submitting the form loads a new page and wipes out the existing one.

Prevent the default form action if the JavaScript is successful.

```
// Capture the event object
...click(function(event){
```

then, at the end:

```
event.preventDefault();
```